# Работа с классами

Tags: php, массивы, ооп, классы

Добрый вечер! Не могу разобраться почему наследуются свойства массива из класса в родительский массив.

А теперь по полочкам. Существует класс объекта:

```
class Obj
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->a = 1;
        $this->b = 2;
        $this->c = 3;
    }
}
```

Создаю массив из этих объектов:

```
$array = array();
$array[] = new Obj;
$array[] = new Obj;
```

После этого мне нужно произвести некоторые действия с этим массивом. Например добавить еще одно свойство TEST с значением 'test' в каждый объект. Для этого я создал еще один класс.

```
class Test2
{
    public function __construct($array)
    {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function addElem()
    {
        $array = $this->array;

        foreach($array as $obj)
        {
            $obj->TEST = 'test';
        }

        $this->array = $array;
    }
}
```

И конечно воплощаю задуманное:

```
$test = new Test2($array);
$test->addElem();
```

И вот что вводит меня в ступор: почему после того, как я создал экземпляр класса Test и добавил значения внутри этого класса, значения так же добавились в массив $array, которая находится ВНЕ класса? И как этого избежать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

меняется не массив, меняются объекты, на которые он ссылается.

PHP работает с объектами иначе, чем с массивами. Обратите внимание, что для того, чтобы менять объекты внутри foreach, вам не надо делать ссылку - `foreach($a as &$i)` - поскольку присваивание `$a = $b` не создает нового объекта - и а, и b будут ссылаться на один объект

Избежать можно только клонированием этих объектов - `$b = clone $a`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло! Пол дня голову ломал... А сейчас пойду учить основы ООП :)

Comment: Это особенности поведения PHP, но учить всяко не вредно :) успехов!